# java getRuntime().exec() with redirection

Tags: java, rdf, jena, runtime.exec

I am trying to execute a terminal command in java yet I get erroneous results (even though the command is being executed). When I paste the same command to the terminal, it yields the correct output. I am guessing the problem occurs because of the redirection characters ('<','>') yet I haven't been able to find a solution. I am using eclipse and osx.
Below is the command, many thanks in advance.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar filePath/rdfslice_1.6.jar "
 +
 "-source filePath/myData.nt -patterns {?s1 <http://www.europeana.eu/schemas/edm/isShownAt> ?o1.} " 
+
"-out filePath/output.out -order S");
```

Comment: This is a guess, but I would normally expect spaces between each item, which you don't get by concatenating those strings.  Can you try adding a space to the end of the those first two strings?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectOutput%28%29

Comment: I suggest to use http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/ library.

Comment: hello soong, yes there are normally spaces, I edited the code while pasting here

Comment: Just a comment, you should also probably use a ProcessBuilder to construct the process.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

Comment: i agree with you and that was my first choice when I started this but somehow I never was able to pass the parameters correctly, runtime exec was the only way helpful

Comment: I deleted my answer because I misunderstood the question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Pass each separate argument (ie "word") of the command as a separate string, `...exec("java", "jar", "filePath/rdfslice_1.6.jar", etc)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Runtime.exec is obsolete and really shouldn't be used for anything anymore.  Its replacement is [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).  You don't have to quote or escape anything when you use it:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
    "java",
    "-jar",
    "filePath/rdfslice_1.6.jar",
    "-source",
    "filePath/myData.nt",
    "-patterns",
    "{?s1 <http://www.europeana.eu/schemas/edm/isShownAt> ?o1.}",
    "-out",
    "filePath/output.out",
    "-order",
    "S");

Process p = builder.inheritIO().start();
```

Comment: hello
I have tried process builder when I first tried executing this command but it somehow didnt work. I tried the exact thing you suggested. yet i will give it another try

Comment: it works very well. i did not use inheritIO() before, maybe that is the reason. thank you

Comment: Without inheritIO(), the process has nowhere to print its standard output or standard error, and may eventually block while waiting for that output to be printed or consumed.  Alternately, you could redirect stdout and stderr to files, or you could create new threads to constantly read from the process's output stream and error stream, but inheritIO() is usually easier.